# PHP: How to use str_replace

Tags: php

I am trying to string replace the following in php

```
{{str_replace('D:\xamp\htdocs\james\', '/', 'D:\xamp\htdocs\james\assets/images/users/58f5f0afc28cb-bigbang2.jpg')}}
```

I get the following error:

> ErrorException: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'D' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `'D:\xamp\htdocs\james\'`. The final `'` is being escaped.

Comment: isn't it preg_replace in you question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `preg_replace` use `str_replace` for exact matching and replacement. 
Problem in your code is you haven't escaped `\` use first parameter as `'D:\xamp\htdocs\james\\'`

```
echo str_replace('D:\xamp\htdocs\james\\', '/', 'D:\xamp\htdocs\james\assets/images/users/58f5f0afc28cb-bigbang2.jpg');
```

**Output:**

`/assets/images/users/58f5f0afc28cb-bigbang2.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

The `'`  is getting escaped here: `'D:\xamp\htdocs\james\'`. That is the reason you are getting the error. You need to escape the `\` to resolve the error.

```
{{preg_replace('D:\xamp\htdocs\james\\', '/','D:\xamp\htdocs\james\assets/images/users/58f5f0afc28cb-bigbang2.jpg')}}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.